# grails sessionFactory.currentSession.flushMode not work with thread?

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, grails, flush, mode

In grails we have the following config:

DataSource.groovy:

`hibernate {
    flush.mode="commit"
}`

which prints "COMMIT" when we log it in a transactional context:

`println "session=${sessionFactory.currentSession.flushMode}"`

but when we create a new thread

this prints "AUTO".

New thread does seem to get the other hibernate settings, ie database, username and factory, but the currentSession doesn't take the flush.mode setting.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Quartz plugin?

Quartz changes the flush mode:
https://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/~raw,r=41198/grails-plugins/grails-quartz/tags/LATEST_RELEASE/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/quartz/listeners/SessionBinderJobListener.java

```
public void jobToBeExecuted(JobExecutionContext context) {
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, true);
session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory, new SessionHolder(session));
    if( LOG.isDebugEnabled()) LOG.debug("Hibernate Session is bounded to Job thread");
}
```

The workaround is to change the flush mode in the Job:

```
        def sessionFactory
        .
        .
        .
        def session=SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, false)
        session?.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT)
```

Comment: We're not using Quartz - but will probably do a 'tactical fix' as you suggest - to set the flushMode on each thread. Will wait a day or so before I mark the question - someone else may have had and fixed the issue.